# what's the reason of the time of MPI_Write changes greatly for different number of processors?

Tags: time, mpi

I am writing an odd-even sorting program using MPI. The coding is finished.

But when I test the time of each part of the program, such as the io time, compute time and communication time, I find the time of IO changes greatly when the number of processor is different.

For example, I test the program using the data who has 100000 elements, the time of writing result is more than 1 second when the process is 3,6,7 or 9, while the time is less than 0.3s when the process is  2, 4, 8,etc.

I let the processors read and write the file evenly, I know this is something about the size of data, but why? I just learn MPI, so I don't know much about it.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using independent or collective i/o?  Are you using a local or parallel file system?  have you benchmarked that file system, particularly with respect to access size?   Are these processes all on the same node, or are you using multiple nodes?  Anyone wishing to help you needs a lot more to work with...